# Where can I find sugar cane?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I played several hours a started three different worlds in Minecraft, but I have never found any sugar canes. I read on Minecraft wiki to search near water but still no luck. Do you have more hints? Is it possible to re-create an environment that allow sugar canes to naturally grow?

Comment: Like your car keys, you're guaranteed to find it as soon as you stop looking for it.

Comment: Also like your car keys, it will always be in the last place you look.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — That phrase has always puzzled me.  Of *course* it's in the last place you look.  Why would you keep looking after you've found it? ;-)

Comment: @Ben I always look in at least one more place, just to prove those people wrong.

Comment: @Ben Blank - that's the irony. I'm poking fun at folks who use the phrase, not realizing that, JavadocMD excepted, that would *have* to be true.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, but your adage doesn’t fit as well as Keaanu’s. Yours means it will be somewhere unexpected which is not the case here; it makes perfect sense to find it at a grassy shore.

Comment: @BenBlank: That's because the phrase is supposed to be "the last place you think to look" as in if you make a list of all places they could be, no matter how you sort them, the keys will always be in the last one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sugar cane (and cactus) only naturally spawn on chunk generation. Sugar cane grows on dirt/grass next to water. The easiest way is to generally walk along a coastline or riverside, and hope you find some.

They're not all that rare for the most part. Use something like Cartograph G to list how many pieces are in your world; maybe you just haven't got any generated yet?

Once you've got one though, you won't need to look for any more, they are extremely efficient to farm!

Comment: What the duck said.  Once you find even one (though they usually grow in clusters) they're very easy to farm... just make rows of dirt with one-block trenches between, and fill the trenches with water source blocks.  Plant (right-click) a piece of sugar cane on the dirt, and watch it grow!  Farm that one when it's 3 high, and plant three more, ad infinitum.

Comment: Crop Circles, Mazes/Labyrinths, Paper -> Books -> Bookshelves -> Library, Flood Gates, Underwater Air Bubbles, etc.  Enjoy! :D

Comment: I made 18*64 sugar cane from only two sugar cane. lol

Comment: I traveled 2 whole days, stopping during nights inside small caves. The whole sea coast was completely clear, but finally I found 6 (!) sugar canes near a insignificant pond of 9 water squares. Now I can go back and try to plant these precious canes.

Answer (score 2):

How old is your map? When I started my first map, in Alpha 1.1 it was a *lot* rarer than it is now, although I don't know when the spawn rate was changed.

Sugar cane only grows on grass/dirt/sand adjacent to water (not diagonally). It spawns in all biomes (except the nether) including tundra, but will die soon after terrain generation there due to it being next to ice rather than water.

Once you have found some, farming is extremely efficient and it's quite easy to create as much as you want. If you really can't find any at all, you can always hack some into your inventory with InvEdit, or similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not finding any around your initial spawn point, you may need to consider going on a long trip.  Pack up some survival gear, and follow a river or the shoreline of an ocean.  Or if you're feeling especially daring, head out into the open sea itself to find those beautiful green stalks of sugar.

The more area you explore, the more likely you are to find new resources. Not just sugar cane, but all kinds of things you haven't yet found.

Once you've got at least a few stalks, remember that sugar cane is perhaps the easiest to grow crop in Minecraft.  Just plop down all the reeds you've collected next to a body of water, and let time pass, and soon enough you'll have quadrupled your stock!

Answer (score 1):

You can find Sugar Cane pretty much anywhere - so long as its planted directly next to water and on dirt, grass or sand. They can grow naturally up to 4 blocks in height, but it takes time for it to grow from 3-4 blocks tall.

To make a farm, put it on a suitable block next to water, wait for it to grow to 3 or 4 high (depending on how long you are willing to wait), mine it up, either use it for crafting or replant it, and repeat. A good time-saving technique is to never mine the bottom cane.

Answer (score 0):

The best places to find it is in the desert or near the ocean.

In my experience I have seen a lot of sugar cane spawn in desert biomes - My house is in the desert and it seems to be everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is make an exact copy of your map, but in creative mode, and fly around the place looking for sugarcane. Everything will be exactly the same in both maps.

This is a lot easier than traveling 'dangerously' day and night in search when it could only take you about a minute.

Comment: Could you explain how you "make an exact copy of the map but in creative" in your answer, as it stands someone wont know what your talking about as as such this answer wont help them at all

Answer (score -2):

If you go next to a river and walk along it chances are you will find some after a while.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said.