# What is the best way to find sugar cane in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a world and I'm making this secret password lock with redstone and all that I need is about 2 stacks of paper so I need help finding sugar cane so I can make a farm and so I can finish my secret lock

Comment: You answered a question identical to this literally 5 min before asking... Maybe try reading the answers on that question.... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22308/where-can-i-find-sugar-cane

Answer (score 0):

Sugarcane is most common along water edges. Find a river nearby and take a boat, while searching for sugarcane on the side.

Comment: He already answered his own question (in the marked duplicate no doubt).